# Secondary sorting script algorithm

Tags: sorting

First, I don't know if the title is appropriate for what I want to do. Maybe it has another name.

So let's say I have a list ordered as follows:

```
dog1
dog2
dog3
cat1
cat2
cat3
hen1
hen2
hen3
```

and what I want is

```
dog1
cat1
hen1
dog2
cat2
hen2
dog3
cat3
hen3
```

Is there a standard algorithm for this, or is it user's choice? What I was thinking was numbering them first and then bringing out the index in front.

```
11dog1
22dog2
33dog3
14cat1
25cat2
36cat3
17hen1
28hen2
39hen3
```

From there I would sort them and then remove the index. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: If you're looking for implementation tips - what language?

Comment: So you want to sort by the trailing decimal value, then by the index?

Comment: I would script it in perl or python. The quick hack I did was using vim.
In this case, the sort is by trailing decimal, then by index (if you mean dog,cat,hen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My idea is that you separate each line in individual arrays.

```
array1 -> dog1, dog2, dog3
array2 -> hen1, hen2, hen3
array3 -> cat1, cat2, cat3
```

Then create another array where to store the result and do something like this:

```
string result[array1.length + array2.length + array3.length];
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    result[counter] = array1[i];
    result[counter + 1] = array2[i];
    result[counter + 2] = array3[i];

    counter += 3;
}
```

Comment: If to transpose a `3*r` array is what the asker wants, this will work. You should generalise to `c*r` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to overload your "<" operator such that:
dog1 < dog2 , dog1 < cat1 ...

Meaning AB < CD = True only if (B < D) or (B==D and A < C)

where A is the character part and B is the numerical part of AB